# ClientHandlerException with a jersey request containing special content type

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, content-type

I'm trying to post a request with this content type : application/x-poh-ws-8-call+json

I am doing stuff like this :

```
ClientResponse resp;

resp = webResource.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, neededAuthorizationHeader)
                 .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-poh-ws-8-call+json")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, request);
```

And here is the exception

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class net.awl.occ.client.models.requests.parameters.occ.ListTransfersRequest, and MIME media type, application/x-poh-ws-8-call+json, was not found
```

I'm using the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider like this

```
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
provider.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
```

Do I have to create a special Provider for this content type ?

Thank you

Comment: Ok it works if I create a JsonProvider extending JacksonJaxbJsonProvider like this : @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json", "application/x-poh-ws-8-call+json"})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/x-poh-ws-8-call+json"})
public class JsonSaHProvider extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
}